# SQLBase and NHibernate?

Tags: sql, nhibernate

Looking for a way to use SQLBase (by Unify, formerly Gupta) with NHibernate. I don't think there is a specific SQLBase provider, but I guess there would be generic providers to connect and use the most common SQL features...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement at least `IDriver`. You can start from `DriverBase` or `ReflectionBasedDriver`.

For the dialect, you can try with `GenericDialect`. But of course you'll have better functionality if you implement a custom `Dialect`.

For both elements, I suggest you look at the source of the existing ones in https://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Driver and https://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Dialect respectively.